# Python subprocess not returning

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to call a Python script from Jenkins and have it build my app, FTP it to the target, and run it.

I am trying to build and the `subprocess` command fails. I have tried this with both `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.popen()`, with the same result.

When I evaluate `shellCommand` and run it from the command line, the build succeeds.

Note that I have 3 shell commands: 1) remove work directory, 2) create a fresh, empty, work directory, then 3) build. The first two commands return from `subprocess`, but the third hangs (although it completes when run from the command line).

What am I doing wrongly? Or, what alternatives do I have for executing that command?

```
# +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
def ExcecuteShellCommandAndGetReturnCode(arguments, shellCommand):
    try:
        process = subprocess.call(shellCommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        #process.wait()
        return process #.returncode

    except KeyboardInterrupt, e: # Ctrl-C
        raise e
    except SystemExit, e: # sys.exit()
        raise e
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Exception while executing shell command : ' + shellCommand
        print str(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        os._exit(1)

# +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
def BuildApplciation(arguments):
    # See http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/

    jenkinsWorkspaceDirectory = arguments.eclipseworkspace + '/jenkins'

    shellCommand = 'rm -r ' + jenkinsWorkspaceDirectory
    ExcecuteShellCommandAndGetReturnCode(arguments, shellCommand)

    shellCommand = 'mkdir ' + jenkinsWorkspaceDirectory
    if not ExcecuteShellCommandAndGetReturnCode(arguments, shellCommand) == 0:
        print "Error making Jenkins work directory in Eclipse workspace : " + jenkinsWorkspaceDirectory
        return False

    application = 'org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild'
    shellCommand = 'eclipse -nosplash -application ' + application + ' -import ' + arguments.buildRoot + '/../Project/ -build myAppApp/TargetRelease -cleanBuild    myAppApp/TargetRelease -data ' + jenkinsWorkspaceDirectory + ' -D DO_APPTEST'
    if not ExcecuteShellCommandAndGetReturnCode(arguments, shellCommand) == 0:
        print "Error in build"
        return False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Googled further and found [this page](https://www.webcodegeeks.com/python/python-subprocess-example/), which, at 1.2 says

> One way of gaining access to the output of the executed command would
>   be to use PIPE in the arguments stdout or stderr, but the child
>   process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up
>   the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.

Sure enough, when I deleted the `, stdout=subprocess.PIPE` from the code above, it worked as expected.

As I only want the exit code from the subprocess, the above code is enough for me. Read the linked page if you want the output of the command.